# Batch file script for attrib

Tags: batch-file, scripting, usb-drive

I want to create a batch file for run attrib script for pen drive.

But problem is pen drive changes.

batch file that 1st ask to write drive letter

Then run attrib script for that drive.

(my pendrive gets virus from class that i want to clear at home by aplying attrib script below everyday

attrib -r -a -s -h /s /d

Answer (score 0):

```
@echo off
set /p drive=Drive letter: 
pushd %drive%:
attrib -r -a -s -h /s /d
popd
```